# Onde encontro as especificações para geração da DARF?

Tags: boleto

Preciso saber onde encontro as especificações da geração da DARF para pagamento atravéz da linha digitável.

Os dados da DARF eu já tenho, gostaria de poder criar o código de barras, de preferência ser usar o site da receita.

Se tiver algum código de exemplo, pode ser em qualquer linguagem, me interessa mesmo é a lógica.

Disponibilizarei o código fonte no GitHub para geração em Python 3 usando o ReportLab após a criação.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo informações encontradas na internet, a partir de 2012 o DARF passou a seguir o padrão criado pela febraban. O layout pode ser encontrado aqui:

http://www.febraban.org.br/7Rof7SWg6qmyvwJcFwF7I0aSDf9jyV/sitefebraban/Codbar4-v28052004.pdf

> Iniciou-se em abril de 2012 a arrecadação com o Darf Numerado.
>   Trata-se de Darf emitido por sistema (não havendo possibilidade de
>   preenchimento manual do documento de arrecadação), com código de
>   barras no padrão Febraban e numerado sequencialmente pelo Sistema
>   Senda. Esta forma de pagamento é semelhante à forma utilizada para o
>   documento de arrecadação do Simples Nacional (DAS).
>
> Atualmente apenas as receitas sob a administração da Secretaria de
>   Patrimônio da União (SPU) estão sendo arrecadadas no Darf Numerado. Em
>   breve outros pagamentos também começarão a ser arrecadados nesta nova
>   sistemática de pagamento.
>
> O Darf Numerado, da mesma forma que o DAS, só poderá ser visualizado
>   no Sistema Sief Documentos de Arrecadação, não sendo possível,
>   portanto, a realização de consulta a este tipo de pagamento no Sistema
>   Sinal.
>
> Não é possível a realização de retificação do Darf Numerado, tendo em
>   vista que os dados constantes da base de pagamentos são gravados pelo
>   sistema emissor do documento, devendo o contribuinte se informar no
>   órgão emitente acerca de possível erro no preenchimento do documento.

Fonte: http://www.fiscosoft.com.br/n/1shws/13062012-darf-e-reformulado-seguindo-o-modelo-do-das-noticias-comunidade-do-simples-nacional

Comment: Ou seja, segundo isso o documento tem que ser gerado pelo Sicalc e não pode ser gerado por um sistema ERP?

Comment: @SergioGarcia pelo que entendi pode sim ser gerado. Na página 6 do layout explica os campos do código de barras.

Comment: Então, o documento não fala sobre o DARF em si, mas sobre documentos de arrecadação e concessionária. Preciso obter uma série de dados que não tem ali. Vou continuar a busca e se conseguir posto a solução e código para isso.